# ExecutorService vs ThreadPoolExecutor using LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, blockingqueue, threadpoolexecutor

I am working on a multithreaded project in which I need to spawn multiple threads to measure the end to end performance of my client code, as I'm doing Load and Performance testing. So I created the below code which is using `ExecutorService`.

Below is the code with `ExecutorService`:

```
public class MultithreadingExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            executor.submit(new NewTask());
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}

class NewTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Measure the end to end latency of my client code
    }   
}
```

**Problem statement:**

Now I was reading some article on the Internet. I found out there is `ThreadPoolExecutor` as well. So I got confused which one I should be using.

If I replace my above code from:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        executor.submit(new NewTask());
    }
```

to:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> threadPool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

ThreadPoolExecutor tpExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 2000, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, threadPool);

tpExecutor.prestartAllCoreThreads();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        tpExecutor.execute(new NewTask());
    }
```

will this make any difference? I am trying to understand what is the difference between my original code using `ExecutorService` and the new code pasted using `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Some of my team mates said second one (ThreadPoolExecutor) is the right way to use.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 93):

Here is the source of `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`:

```
 public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

It internally uses `ThreadPoolExecutor` class with default configuration as you can see above. Now there are scenarios where default configuration is not suitable say instead of `LinkedBlockingQueue` a priority queue needs to be used etc. In such cases caller can directly work on underlying  `ThreadPoolExecutor` by instantiating it and passing desired configuration to it.

Answer (score 33):

> then that will make any difference?

It will make your code more complicated for little benefit.

> I am trying to understand what is the difference between my original code which is using ExecutorService and the new code, that I pasted which is using ThreadPoolExectuor?

Next to nothing.  `Executors` creates a ThreadPoolExecutor to do the real work.

> Some of my team mates said second one (ThreadPoolExecutor) is right way to use?

Just because it's more complicated doesn't mean it's the right thing to do.  The designers provided the Executors.newXxxx methods to make life simpler for you and because they expected you to use those methods.  I suggest you use them as well.

Comment: You talked about some little benefit? What is that all about? And behind the scene Executors called ThreadPoolExecutor right? But I believe it uses Unbounded queue which is slightly slow I guess? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The little benefit is you can play with the constructor arguments, but this is usually not a good idea. You provided the same unbounded queue, so I don't see your point.  If it was slow, why would the designers use it?

Comment: There is a cost in using LinkedBoundedQueue. It has nothing to do with the fact it is unbounded and it is very small compared to the cost of passing tasks between threads, which I assume you are not too worried about.

Comment: For me there is an important difference, because I need to adjust the number of threads dynamically.

Answer (score 15):

1. [Executors#newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newFixedThreadPool%28int%29)

   ```
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
   ```

is basically

```
 return new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 20,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

2.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> threadPool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
ThreadPoolExecutor tpExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 2000, 0L,
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, threadPool);
```

In the second case, you are just increasing the maxPoolSize to 2000, which I doubt you would need.

Answer (score 4):

I believe one more advantage is with RejectionHandler. Correct me if wrong

Answer (score 3):

In first example, You have created just 20 threads with below statement

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
```

In second example, you have set the thread limits range in between `20 to 2000`

```
 ThreadPoolExecutor tpExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 2000, 0L, 
                                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,threadPool);
```

*More threads are available for processing. But you have configured task queue as unbounded queue.*

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)  would be more effective if you have customized many or all of below parameters.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, 
               int maximumPoolSize, 
               long keepAliveTime, 
               TimeUnit unit, 
               BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, 
               ThreadFactory threadFactory,
               RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

`RejectedExecutionHandler` would be useful when you set `max capacity for workQueue` and number of tasks, which have been submitted to Executor are more than `workQueue` capacity.

Have a look at Rejected tasks section in [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of `GC out of memory exception`, `ThreadPoolExecutor` saved my life. :)

As Balaji said,

> [..] one more advantage is with RejectionHandler.

In my case I had a lot of `RejectedExecutionException` and specifying (as follow) the discard policy solved all my problems.

```
private ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, cpus, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
```

But be careful! It works only if you **don't** need to execute **all** the threads that you submit to the executor.

For further information about `ThreadPoolExecutor` take a look at [Darren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518588/5545873)