# ThreadPoolExecutor Vs ExecutorService for service time out use cases

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I am going to implement Timeout framework between two services. I am looking at **pros & cons** of `ThreadPoolExecutor` VS  `ExecutorService`

Code with ExecutorService.

```
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for ( int i=0; i<10; i++){
            MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable((long)i);
            Future<Long> futureResult = service.submit(myCallable);
            Long result = null;
            try{
                result = futureResult.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }catch(TimeoutException e){
                System.out.println("Time out after 5 seconds");
                futureResult.cancel(true);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                System.out.println("Error: Interrupted");
            }catch(ExecutionException ee){
                System.out.println("Error: Execution interrupted");
            }
            System.out.println("Result:"+result);
        }
        service.shutdown();
```

Code snippet for MyCallable

```
class MyCallable implements Callable{
    Long id = 0L;

    public MyCallable(Long val){
        this.id = val;
    }

    public Long call(){
        // **Call a service and get id from the service**
        return id;
    }
}
```

If I want to implement with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, I will code in this way

```
/* Thread pool Executor */
    BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(300);
    ThreadPoolExecutor eventsExecutor =
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 10, 60,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue, new MyRejectionHandler());
/* I can submit the tasks as for above code example used in future */
```

Now I am looking at pros & cons of using `ThreadPoolExecutor`  Vs  `ExecutorService`. Please don't think that this question is duplicate of [ExectuorService vs ThreadPoolExecutor (which is using LinkedBlockingQueue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161941/exectuorservice-vs-threadpoolexecutor-which-is-using-linkedblockingqueue).

**I have some queries after reading above question and hence posted this question.**

1. It was recommended to use `ExecutorSevice` with `Executors.XXX methods`. If I use `Executors.XXX()` methods, do I have capabilities to set `RejectionHandler`, `BlockingQueue` size etc? If not, Do I have to fall back on `ThreadPoolExecutor`?
2. Does `ThreadPoolExecutor` implemented by `ExeuctorService` offers unbounded queue? I am implementing `Timeout` framework between two services.

***Which one is best option between these two? Or Do I have other best option ?***

Comment: "ThreadPoolExecutor wrapped by ExeuctorService" ThreadPoolExecutor *implements* ExecutorService, it isn't wrapped by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. It was recommended to use ExecutorSevice with Executors.XXX methods. If I use Executors.XXX() methods, do I have capabilities to set RejectionHandler, BlockingQueue size etc? If not, Do I have to fall back on ThreadPoolExecutor?

No, you can't specify these things via `Executors` factory methods. However, take a look at the source code of `Executors`: you will see that its `newXXX` methods simply wrap calls to create `ThreadPoolExecutor` instances.

As such, there is no particular advantage to using `Executors`, aside from the convenience of not having to specify many of the parameters. If you need to specify these additional capabilities, you will need to create the `ThreadPoolExecutor` instances directly.

> 2. Does ExeuctorService offers unbounded queue? I am implementing Timeout framework between two services. Which one is best option between these two? Or Do I have other best option (e.g. CountDownLatch etc.)

`ExecutorService` is an interface: it offers you nothing by way of implementation details such as unbounded queues.

Comment: Now I changed the second query. Does ThreadPoolExecutor wrapped by ExecutorService offers unbounded queue?

Comment: ExecutorService is an interface: it returns whatever the implementation decides to return; however, no method on ExecutorService returns an ExecutorService like a ThreadPoolExecutor. Assuming you really mean Executors, you should read the Javadoc, which makes it pretty clear.

Comment: Got the answer for Unbounded queue. It's unbounded. Earlier I checked at wrong place.

Comment: public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.

Comment: I also thought of the same on usage of ThreadPoolExecutor. But after reading experts comments in other question I mentioned in the post, I got doubt that ExecutorService.getXXX is the right way. Thanks for your confirmation.