# Best practice for executing large number of tasks

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Below code creates large number of runnable object in loop, even only 5 treads are there to process the tasks. Is there any way so that at any moment only 5 runnable object will be present in memory not the total number of tasks( 100000).

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
    System.out.println("ExecutorExample.main()");
    executor.execute(worker);
}
```

Comment: create 5, submit, wait for completion then create 5 again etc until you have the 10000 ??

Comment: Create an `ExecutorServce` to manage the other five services and assign new jobs, that way your main thread won't hang as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement that at any moment only 5 runnable object will be present in memory is too restrictive. When a task finishes, there would be no next task to run, and some time would be spend to create another task. Better to have 5 runnung tasks and 5 waiting in a line. In order to restrict the number of the tasks in the queue, use a BlockingQueue of fixed size for runnables, e.g.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
     5, 5,
     10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
     new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5)
)
```

UPDT To avoid RejectedExecutionException, add RejectedExecutionHandler, as proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518588/1206301:

```
RejectedExecutionHandler block = new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            try {
                executor.getQueue().put(r);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(block);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use this in above scenario.

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj just replace the first line in your program with what I proposed and leave the rest intact.

Comment: Only 10 tasks are run due to `Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException...`

Comment: It's probably worth stressing the quotes from the post you are referring to: "Now. This is a very bad idea for the following reasons" (3 given), but then "However, sometimes a blocking strategy, with all its inherent risks, is really what you want". Or maybe you don't agree with the reasons to not use it given there?

Comment: @starikoff I actually don't think this idea is that bad. For the given use case, it works well.

Comment: Sure. I would include it as a warning to whoever comes to this question and answer later with a different use case and doesn't follow the link, but it's your call definitely (: