# Multithreading with nested for loops in java

Tags: java, multithreading

How to multithread a task among nesting for-loops (say 2).
Consider the task is to find the GCD(x,y) where 'x' and 'y' are large, say 10^6.
I create 10 threads and want each thread to compute GCD for unique (x,y).

Comment: What have you tried, so far?

Comment: is computing GCD(x,y) for each argument pair independent of computing for other arguments? That is, is GCD(x,y) pure function without side effects?

Comment: yes  @AlexeiKaigorodov Kaigorodov its independent

Comment: Do you know how to start a thread? Do you know how to wait for a thread to finish? If not, do some reading. If so, what's your problem?

Comment: @slim , my problem is not "how to use ",its "where" and "when" to use.

Answer (score 0):

The solution consists of 3 parts. The central part is a queue of restricted size to keep small tasks each of which computes GCD(x,y) for given x and y. First part is a thread which makes nesting for-loops and for each x and y makes new task and puts it to the queue. When the queue is full, method queue.put() blocks to avoid memory saturation.
The last part is a pool of threads which take tasks from the queue and execute them. You can implement working threads from scratch, or make a thread pool with blocking queue as it is described in [Best practice for executing large number of tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924429/best-practice-for-executing-large-number-of-tasks/44925651)