# Limiting the number of spawned Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I've run into a problem which I hope you gurus can help with.

I'm designing a multi threaded Java application which I would like to limit the number of spawned threads to 5 at any one time. The main() program should **paused and wait until a thread is available from the pool** until resuming it's process.

At the moment here is what I have come up with BUT it seems that the way I am detecting the number of active threads is not very accurate.

Just wondering if there is another way to do this.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){    
  System.out.println("current number of threads: "+((ThreadPoolExecutor)pool).getActiveCount());

  while(true){
      if (((ThreadPoolExecutor)pool).getActiveCount() < 5)
          break;
      Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
      System.out.println("waiting ..... "+((ThreadPoolExecutor)pool).getActiveCount());
  }

  Runnable sampleThread = new SampleThread(100);
  pool.submit(sampleThread );
}

**************************************************
** Output:
**************************************************
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 1
current number of threads: 1
current number of threads: 1
current number of threads: 1
```

Is there an alternative way to achieve what i'm trying to do ?
I did some research and nothing quite fits the bill.

Thanks in Advance,
Edmond

Comment: The `pool` will not have more than 5 active threads at any point. What's the concern?

Comment: What do you mean that they are not very accurate?

Comment: why can't you just keep submitting tasks and let the Executor handle it.

Comment: Searching for (the task) "java blocking thread pool" found results like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001086/how-to-make-threadpoolexecutors-submit-method-block-if-it-is-saturated I'm not really sure what the posted code is supposed to do or show and it looks like, perhaps, the threads are *very* shortlived.

Comment: read this: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html

Comment: you may need your own customize [thread pool](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#trpool).

Answer (score 1):

You are the newFixedThreadPool from java.util.concurrent.Executors for this - it aleady limits to 5 threads. Are you sure its not already limited to 5 threads without any further moderation?

Comment: Thats what I stated - rephrased it

Comment: What I meant in my first comment was emphasis on CAN, as in: there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I am unable to undo my negative vote unless you make an edit to your answer. Also, this is more of a comment in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer without knowing what SampleThread does. If it does nothing time consuming, then the thread might have finished before the loop continues. For instance

```
public static class SampleThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

}
```

returns

```
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 0
```

but

```
public static class SampleThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

returns

```
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 1
current number of threads: 2
current number of threads: 3
current number of threads: 4
current number of threads: 5
waiting ..... 0
current number of threads: 0
current number of threads: 1
current number of threads: 2
current number of threads: 3
current number of threads: 4
current number of threads: 5
waiting ..... 0
```

Can you edit the post with information about what SampleThread does?

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, sample thread is responsible for sending out email notifications to my clients.

Since sending out emails (up to 100) will take a long time i'm concerned that the thread queue will be overloaded and memory resources will be exhausted.

Is it something to be concerned about ?