# Max. created Threads with Threadpool Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, mergesort

I have to write a code for concurrent Mergesort and my problem is, if the merge sort implementation wants to create a new thread, it has to check if there is a thread slot available or not ( so i created a Threapool(max 5 Threads).It is also working, but my problem is that i should only use 5 threads without reusing them.

That means if there are no more thread slots available the thread just performs for its array part the traditional recursive merge sort algorithm.

```
    int nThreads = 5;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        Runnable worker = new Mergesort(array);
        executor.execute(worker);           
    }
    executor.shutdown();

    while(!executor.isTerminated()) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that as mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001086/how-to-make-threadpoolexecutors-submit-method-block-if-it-is-saturated). Especially refer to the answer by user **danben**.

However, you need to make sure to yourself that the count of 5 which you state includes the main thread also or not - that is does the count of 5 mean mainthread + 4 threads  **or** 5 worker threads.

Hope this points you in a direction to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you alot!! I think CallerRunsPolicy() is the thing what im looking for :)